# How to dynamically change the docker's base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have two dockerfiles, which are exactly  same with the only difference being the FROM statement. The problem I have is whenever I modify something in one file I have to do the same in another, because they have to be the same.

One solution for this would be to pass base image as parameter to docker build command. I don't know if that is possible.

Another would be to have some kind of include files mechanism. In that case I would implement all common steps in a separate file which I would just include in my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could make use of image tagging to handle this.

Change the FROM to something like:

```
FROM base-image
```

Then just tag RHEL or Centos "base-image" before you do the build (using -f)

```
$ docker tag -f centos base-image
$ docker build -t my_image/builtfromcentos .
$ docker tag -f rhel base-image
$ docker build -t my_image/builtfromrhel .
```

Comment: I was just a bit confused with your example as you seem to use two different images 'builtfromcentos' and 'builtfromrhel', but I tried using same image in both cases and it worked.

Comment: Neat idea but does not work if I want to concurrently build docker images that differ in tag of base-image.

Comment: Looks like FROM can be defined using an ARG in the meantime: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/use-arg-dockerfile-dynamic-image-specification

Answer (score 59):

From Docker version 17.05, you can do something like this:

```
ARG MYAPP_IMAGE=myorg/myapp:latest
FROM $MYAPP_IMAGE
```

You can provide `MYAPP_IMAGE` as a command line paramether:

```
docker build -t container_tag --build-arg MYAPP_IMAGE=localimage:latest .
```

More info here: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/use-arg-dockerfile-dynamic-image-specification

Comment: This works! By mistake tried in a docker version 16 environment and didn't work but version 18 worked. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason. I get `invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase` when using this.

Comment: @cyberbeast maybe you need to put some kind of quotes around `MYAPP_IMAGE=repository/image`, depending on the OS you are using?

Comment: @AntonKrosnev Turns out the error I was getting didn't have anything to do with docker. I was grabbing some image off of gcr.io 's public registry (distroless images) and I had the `DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST` value set to `1`. Google Container Registry does not implement the docker content trust mechanism and hence throwing the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 10):

You can have multiple FROM statements in a Dockerfile.
Like for example:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM centos:latest
COPY config /tmp/config
EXPOSE 9080 8080
```

will create two images.
From the Docker reference [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/from):

> FROM can appear multiple times within a single Dockerfile in order to
>   create multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

In my attempt to automate the whole process, I created a bash script.

In the bash script, I ran the following command

```
sed -i "1 s|.*|FROM ${sourceRegistryUrl}|" Dockerfile
docker build --tag katoneImage:latest .
```

What that does is it replaces the first line (FROM ...) of Dockerfile, deleting the entire first line and replacing it with the sourceRegistryUrl I want.  Then I run the docker build command (with a specific tag name).  This works pretty well.

So instead of running the Dockerfile directly, I run the "bash script", which chains one command with the next until my entire process is automated.