# Push multiple docker images to manifest without tags

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, containers, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have a GitLab CI job that builds multiple architectures of the same application into docker images. I'd like to push them up to DockerHub *without* needing to tag each image. That way I can add them to a manifest without polluting the tags directory with a bunch of duplicate images.

For example -- from this set of tags:

- r1234 (a manifest containing the below)
- r1234-amd64
- r1234-arm64
- r1234-armv7
- r1234-gui (a manifest containing the below, each image based on the one above)
- r1234-amd64-gui
- r1234-arm64-gui
- r1234-armv7-gui

to this:

- r1234 (manifest containing the same images, without tags)
- r1234-gui (similarly)

Is this something possible? I made this code right now to push up the tags and make a manifest, but I'm not sure how to adapt it.

```yaml
- >
        for arch in $DEPLOY_ARCHS; do
          NEW_IMAGE_NAME="${REPO_PATH}:${REVISION}-${arch}${TAG_EXTRAS}"
          docker pull "${INDEV_IMAGE_NAME}-${arch}${TAG_EXTRAS}"
          docker tag "${INDEV_IMAGE_NAME}-${arch}${TAG_EXTRAS}" "${NEW_IMAGE_NAME}"
          docker push "${NEW_IMAGE_NAME}" # I want to be able to push to the manifest without tagging
          export IMAGES="$IMAGES ${NEW_IMAGE_NAME}"
        done
    - docker manifest create ${REPO_PATH}:${REVISION}${TAG_EXTRAS} ${IMAGES}
    - docker manifest push --purge ${REPO_PATH}:${REVISION}${TAG_EXTRAS}
```

Is this something possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution I came to -- though for most people the added steps and workarounds here are unnecessary when compared to Jean's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68145663/1709894). You should go with that answer unless you specifically need what mine provides.

I wanted to run the builds on different machines -- an arm box and an amd64 box -- to achieve better build speeds than qemu could provide. However, GitLab  / GitHub runners can't communicate with each other, so I couldn't use buildx's ability to run on multiple machines natively. What I came up with was to build the images, push them to an intermediate registry (or export & import them locally if no registry is avaliable was available), pull & use them as cache for another final buildx.

Something like this in GitLab CI:

```yaml
# Build your images separately however you need, tagging with -${arch}

# Do testing on the image to make sure it validates, then...

deploy_image:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - >
      for arch in "amd64 arm64 armv7"; do
        export name="$<YOUR CONTAINER URL AND TAG>-${arch}"
        docker pull "NAME" # or `docker load`
        export ARCH_IMAGES_CACHE="$ARCH_IMAGES_CACHE --cache-from $NAME"
      done
    # Docker will detect that the images we pulled are entirely cacheable, and use those without building
    - docker buildx build --push --pull $ARCH_IMAGES_CACHE --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --platform="linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7" -t "$<YOUR CONTAINER URL>:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}" .
```

There are probably better methods or abstractions that could be done using `docker manifest` or `docker buildx imagetools`, but this was the best solution I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

You want to build [multi-arch images](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/) and it can be done using buildx (assuming they share the same dockerfile in the current directory):

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t yourorg/your-image-name:r1234 --push .
```

On Gitlab-CI this should look like this :

```
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

build-multi-arch-images:
  stage: build-images
  image: jdrouet/docker-with-buildx:stable
  script:
   - docker buildx create --use
   - docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t yourorg/your-image-name:r1234 --push .

stages:
  - build-images
```

Then for r1234-gui I would suggest a second dockerfile using this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49939610/8416360) at the top:

```
ARG MYAPP_IMAGE=yourorg/your-image-name:latest
FROM $MYAPP_IMAGE
```

Which will allow you to provide MYAPP_IMAGE as a command line paramether:

```
docker buildx build -f yourdockerfile --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t yourorg/your-image-name:r1234-gui --build-arg MYAPP_IMAGE=yourorg/your-image-name:r1234 --push .
```

Comment: Thanks, Jean! This is very close to something I came up with, however unfortunately it doesn't work for my specific use case. The build using qemu takes several hours, but on native hardware takes ~20 mins. I split the build to use different runners (an arm machine, and a amd64 machine). I don't believe buildx supports that, as the runners can't communicate with each other. For other users that can run the build on the same machine, this is what I've found to be the optimal solution.